# Master-Detail Interface for os x

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, master-detail

I am working on a MAC Application which has layout similar to Master-Detail relationship like on Left side I have shortcut links to page and on right side different view is going to be shown. So I want to user Master-Detail.

I am using xib with objective c language.

I am basically from iOS background I google about it but didn't find any reference which help me to build this kind of interface.

Please suggest me some reference or guide me how to begin with master-detail.

Thanks

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it. I just use an NSSplitView with an NSOutlineView on the left and changing custom NSViews on the right depending on what's selected in the left view.

Comment: I can't find a guide or reference. Do you want something like the sample code [TableViewPlayground](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727)?

Comment: I have an introduction to something like this in my YouTube video on Cocoa architecture. Should have part 2 up by the end of this week. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy0-x-Zf1YE